# Google Maps v3: Any way to force a high maximum Zoom Level (maxZoom 24)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We are working on an archaeological mapping project where we have georeferenced hundreds of hand drawn maps.  These are all viewable at very high zoom levels, which translates in Google Maps to zoom levels 22, 23 and 24.

However, by default, the [[image]google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps) Type `Map` goes only up to `zoom` level 21.

I have tried several methods to force the max zoom level to go up to 24, but several methods suggested here have proven to be clunky and inconsistent (for example, forcing the user to switch to satellite and then back to Maps to get it to work).

Does anybody know how to enforce a `maxZoom` of 24 efficiently?

Answer (score 3):

**Google Maps API** has a property called `numZoomLevels`.

You need to configure your Google layer with an appropriate `numZoomLevels` value, and also override the internal default for the maximum zoom level with `MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL`. The latter will cause unexpected behavior if the Google layer does not support all zoom levels.

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.Google('Satellite', {
    type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    numZoomLevels: 23,
    MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL: 22
});
```

Also take a look into [[image] **Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).